# Twig Date Translation without Intl extension

Tags: symfony, date, twig, translation

I am working in Symfony 2.7, but my server doesn't have the "php intl extension" installed. I need to manage dates betwing 1900 and 1970.

**How can I show the date in Spanish (or maybe in others languages)?**

I can see lots of solutions, but which one is the best?? There is another one that it is better??

1. Create a new Twig Extension, and use "strftime()" funtion in php (Is it supports dates before 1970?).
2. Create a new Twig Extension, and use an array to translate it (it is not bad, but a little bit dirty)
3. Generate a Twig inline array, to translate the date (it is a little bit dirty, isn't it?).
4. Use the proper translation of Symfony or maybe I18n (but is a little bit heavy only for months and days of the week, isn't it?). Same thing like this: `{{ sDate | date("l") | trans }}`

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

use the [date Filter in Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html#date) or the [format option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#format) in your forms

Comment: What?? I think that you don't understand me. The "Date filter" doesn't translate the name of the day. I need the date like **"Monday 1st"** but in Spanish (Lunes 1). But thkans

Comment: I see. In that case i would create a Twig extension. That will work fine.

Comment: Okis, then, because your anwser is the only one, Twig Extension :-D Thanks a lot.